# Any viewstate implementation for JSP-Servlet app?

Tags: jsp, viewstate

Do you know any implementation / technique which would provide similar behavior as Viewstate provides in ASP.NET. (Serializing the data into hidden field within the HTML form).

I am using only JSP, Servlet, and Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/) framework provides that.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Webflow offers a similar facility, scoped to individual conversations.  [The persistence section of the manual](http://static.springframework.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch06.html) should be able to explain the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it JSP . get object steam and cover to ASCII data by using base64 
Hareesh